# How can I hide the values in matrix when it is collapsed?

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to create matrix view. When I have it expanded, value doesn't show at the top as expected however, when I collapse it I keep getting values. These value makes  no sense so would like to hide. I tried isinscope function but couldn't hide the values.  I would like to hide yellow highlighted data. Please note I have shown measure I am using:

I used Measure = if (ISINSCOPE(CAA_KPI_TOPIC[Topic]),[Measure 2],blank()) but this didn't solve the issue.

[image]

I calculated Measure 2 as

Measure 2 = Sum(CAA_KPI_DATA[DATA])

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Sam

Please find pbix file here:

This is the result I get :

[image]

https://file.io/zHeOvTbz1JYz

Comment: Can you share the .pbix?

Comment: @DavideBacci, I have added .pbix. file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ISINSCOPE should use the second rows, so change [topic] into [kpis_name]:

```
Measure = if (ISINSCOPE(CAA_KPI_KPIS[KPIS_NAME]),[Measure 2],"")
```

*Sample:*

[image]

Comment: When I corrected it, I got blank. No result at all.

Comment: i think the sample shows the result you want. then maybe your matrix table from different tables and have other problems, let me see your pbix file.

Comment: I have added pbix file.

Comment: updated answer. copy the Measure formula and add into value replace measure2.

Comment: I did what you suggested,  I replaced measure formula and replaced value with measure instead of measure 2 but  I am still not getting what you have in your screenshot. Please see the result i get in my screenshot.  I have edited my post with new screenshot. Thank you

Comment: update with GIF in Answer.

Comment: Sia, I just realized when you do that it moves all KPI_names into all topics. How do  you prevent that from doing?

Comment: Hi Sam, not quite sure about your confusion. Do you mean there is only one "total" row in table without topics show? I have added GIF in answer, in the visual rows click [TOPIC_NAME] and click the second bottom "show items with no data" (it will mark as "√") then all topics will show.

Comment: Hi Sia, apologies for late response. WHen I check the show items with no data, it will show items with no data in all level. Which each topic, you will see all kpi name even if they are blank.

Comment: Hi Sam, I got your point. Change the Measure to be : Measure = if (ISINSCOPE(CAA_KPI_KPI[KPIS_NAME]),[Measure 2],"")   then problem will solved. I cannot attached pbix file in answer, if you need pbix file then please give me one email address.

Comment: Sia, can you please send pbix to shonesum@gmail.com. Thank you. When I used this measure, I got total again. >.<

Comment: Hi Sam, file sent you by email. Let me know if still any confusions.

Comment: Thank you Sia.  I was able to get it to work. You are the best :)

Comment: It's no problem. Glad to hear that hhhh 

Answer (score 0):

Correct your measure

```
Measure = if (ISINSCOPE(CAA_KPI_TOPIC[Topic]),blank(),[Measure 2])
```

Comment: When I used this measure, I just got blank. No result at all.